# Why i get two diferent request from similiar data?

Tags: android, rest, retrofit2, android-notifications

I have two rest request in my retrofit - `PUT` and `DELETE`, both of them use the same data but PUT acts different than DELETE.

```java
@PUT ("api/notifications/enable/{registerID}")
    Call<ResponseBody> notifyRegister(
            @Path("registerID") String registerID,
            @Header("Authorization") String authKey,
            @Body NotifyRegisterModel notifyRegistermodel
    );

    @DELETE ("api/notifications/unregister/{registerID}")
    Call<ResponseBody> notifyUnregister(
            @Path("registerID") String registerID,
            @Header("Authorization") String authKey
    );
```

1st call

```java
Call<ResponseBody> call = RetrofitClient.getInstance().getApi().notifyRegister(SharedPreferenceManager.read(SharedPreferenceManager.RegisterID,""),SharedPreferenceManager.read(SharedPreferenceManager.TOKEN,""),notifyRegisterModel);
```

2nd call

```java
Call<ResponseBody> logout = new RetrofitClient().getApi().notifyUnregister(SharedPreferenceManager.read(SharedPreferenceManager.RegisterID,""),SharedPreferenceManager.read(SharedPreferenceManager.TOKEN, ""));
```

RegisterID from SharedPreferences `7052639164213006488-1018039756675611882-3`

so i should get:

```
/api/notifications/enable/7052639164213006488-1018039756675611882-3

/api/notifications/unregister/7052639164213006488-1018039756675611882-3
```

but i send:

```
/api/notifications/enable/125142881196382515-3202313051333429044-3

/api/notifications/unregister/7052639164213006488-1018039756675611882-3
```

I don't know how registerID in `DELETE` is good when on `PUT` is wrong.

Of course i receive response code `200` from `PUT`.

OK i have some clue

```java
call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                if (response.code() == 200) {
                    Log.d("RegID", "Success");
                }
                else Log.d("RegID", "Fail");
```

I have 2 breakpoints: 1st at `call.enqueue()`, and 2nd at `if(response.code() == 200)`
before call i have
registerID = 1750708241992007604-4373066693001072085-2, 
and after 4086535268576340031-4810276405479782670-1

Comment: `SharedPreferenceManager.read(SharedPreferenceManager.RegisterID, "")` might return two different values... or the value of `SharedPreferenceManager.RegisterID` might have changed in the meanwhile.

Comment: It's impossible, I use these functions one after the other. Get RegisterID->save to SharePreferences->call->logout. Between I put only ```Log.d()``` to know what is happening without debuging. I found out  it changes on ```call.enqueue()``` but don't change on ```logout.enqueue()```